# Remove templates from "Create from Installed" List

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to clean up our custom site templates that are offered up in the `Create from Installed` area.

I have searched the Solutions Gallery and the items I wish to remove are not found there - likely previously deleted at the Gallery level.  Likewise I have opened the Recycled Items and it is empty.

Ideas?

Comment: This type of question should go on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com as it is related to SharePoint management and not programming.